# Error: client intended to send too large body

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload, server

I am using django-resto to upload my media files to remote server. However when I tried to upload, it gives me `django_resto.storage: Failed on create`.

And Log generated below messages,

```
open() "/var/www/media/media/events/video/clipcanvas_14348_H264_640x360.mp4"
failed (2: No such file or directory),
    client: 172.17.42.1,
    server: ,
    request: "HEAD /media/events/video/clipcanvas.mp4 HTTP/1.1",
    host: "IP:8081"

client intended to send too large body:
    body: 2139606 bytes,
    client: *.*.*.*,
    server: ,
    request: "PUT /media/events/video/clipcanvas.mp4 HTTP/1.1",
    host: "IP:8081"
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting such an error?

Settings for Media Server,

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_resto.storage.DistributedStorage'
RESTO_MEDIA_HOSTS = ['IP:8081']
```

Nginx configuration,

```
server { 
    listen 192.168.0.10; 
    location / { 
        root /var/www/media; 
        dav_methods PUT DELETE; 
        create_full_put_path on; 
        dav_access user:rw group:r all:r; 
        allow 192.168.0.1/24; deny all;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you using nginx or Apache?

Answer (score 21):

This issue will be caused by nginxs low default `client_max_body_size` value (1MB).

You will need to set the [`client_max_body_size <value>`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) to something higher in one of the following context blocks:

- http
- location
- server

The code will be something like this:

```
server {
    # set the max body size across the site to be 20mb
    client_max_body_size 20m;
}
```

Personally I would put the `client_max_body_size` on a `location` block. This means that your new max body size will not be globally set and instead set for a particular sub location of your website.

```
server {
    # site default is 1mb
    client_max_body_size 1m;


    location /user/profiles/upload {
        # profile images should be no more than 2m
        client_max_body_size 5m;
        # the rest of your website will still use 1m max body size
    }
}
```

**note:** Remember you will need to reload your config file before changes take affect.

**also note:** You only make the `client_max_body_size` the value you need plus a little bit. Stops people potentially sending up massively huge files in an attempt to cripple your server.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but this was not my problem. I already put 24m as body size. My problem is solved by,
`server {
    listen 192.168.0.10;
    location / {
        root /var/www/media;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE;
        create_full_put_path on;
        dav_access user:rw group:r all:r;
        allow 192.168.0.1/24;
        deny all;
    }
}
` <br />
to <br />
`server {
    listen 192.168.0.10;
    location / {
        root /var/www/media;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE;
        create_full_put_path on;
        dav_access group:rw all:r;
        allow 192.168.0.1/24;
        deny all;
    }
}
`

Comment: Can i suggest you add this to the question as an edit.